# Can I mount an external NTFS drive as writable when running the install DVD?

Tags: macos, external-disk, mount, ntfs

I have an old Macbook Pro on which I'd like to try Mavericks. Before doing so I want to make a back-up of my current Mac OS X install (10.6.8).

I will use the disk utility option (and not the time machine option), as outlined [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1553), since I already have a 1TB NTFS disk, that I use for other back-ups as well. However, NTFS is mounted read-only, by default. Since I don't feel like creating a FAT partition on this disk, nor feel like purchasing another HDD (because 1TB is more than enough for my back-up needs) I want to mount the disk writable.

Now, I know I should be able to mount NTFS drives by tinkering with `/etc/fstab`. However, I assume that `/etc/fstab` will not be read when booting from the install disk. Is that correct?

If so, my question is: can I mount an external NTFS drive as writable when running the install DVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

I opened a terminal window and executed [`mount_ntfs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/mount_ntfs.8.html) similar to this:

```
mount_ntfs -s -o rw /dev/diskXsY /Volumes/SomeMountDirectory
```

where:

1. `-o rw` is the crucial part and means use the readwrite option;
2. `-s` means mount case sensitive;
3. `/dev/diskXsY` represents the actual partition to mount (in my case `/dev/disk8s5`);
4. `/Volumes/SomeMountDirectory` represents the mount point.

Comment: This may let you copy files to NTFS (with loss of some info e.g. file owner etc) BUT it won't let you restore OSX

Comment: I've created a complete `.dmg` disk copy of `Macintosh HD` on that NTFS disk. That should be sufficient to completely restore from, shouldn't it?